# R filter a dataframe with list of lists recursively

Tags: r, list, dataframe, ggplot2, dplyr

I have multiple lists that I would like to use to filter a dataframe and plot with ggplot.
The lists contain data from a column - df$old
I want to recursively take an item from lists and filter the data using the corresponding list and plot a barplot using the filtered list with title corresponding to list name
The filtering step isn't working. I've tried a bunch of methods with no luck and I can't find this question quite answered.
I feel like I want to use rlist, but also can't quite get it to work.
Packages used - dplyr, reshape2, ggplot2
Working in rnotebook

```
Row.names t1  t2  t3  t4  t5  old new
to_delete 10  -2  -8  12  10  g1  gr1
to_delete -5  18  11  -6  10  g2  gr2
.
.
.

lists <- c(a, b, c)
a <- c("g1", "g5", "g8")
b <- c("g2", "g3", "g9")
c <- c("g4", "g6", "g7")

for(i in lists){
  print(i)
  df_sub <- filter(df, grepl(paste(i, collapse="|"), old))
  df_sub$Row.names <- NULL
  df_sub <- melt(df_sub, id.vars=c("old", "new"))
  p <- ggplot(data=df_sub, aes(x= old, y=value, fill = variable)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.5) +
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
    labs(title = paste(i," genes"), x = NULL, y = expression("log"["2"]*" fold change"), fill = "time vs shaking") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size  = 8, angle = 45, hjust = 1, vjust = 1)) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("999999", "E69F00", "56B4E9", "red", "black"))
  print(p)
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what's going wrong?  I'm guessing you want `lists` to be a list of vectors, not a single vector.  If that's true you need `list()` instead of `c()`.

Comment: @aosmith Ugh... Overlooked that and wasted too much time. Making 'lists' a list of vectors is exactly what i needed to do. Thank you!

Comment: The only issue now is that the title is coming out as the first item in each list instead of the name of the list (I want the names to be 'a gene' 'b gene' and 'c gene')

Comment: If you need to loop through both the list and the list names, you may want to loop through the list length instead and use it as an index: like `for(i in 1:3)` and `list[[i]]` or `names(list)[i]`.  This is the kind of situation that I might approach with `map2` from **purrr** for its convenience.

Comment: @aosmith Yes. That worked beautifully. Thank you!